# Picking individual colours from a RColorBrewer palette as a scale_colour_manual() value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `scale_colour_manual()`, can one pick specific colours from RColorBrewer to use as colour values?

For instance, in:

```
scale_colour_manual(breaks=c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
    values=c("green","orange","blue","pink","yellow"))
```

I'd like to use the first colour from the palette `scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 7)` instead of "green", then the fourth colour of the palette `scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 2)` instead of "orange", and so on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I often do the following,

```
library(RColorBrewer)
my_palette = c(brewer.pal(5, "Set1")[c(1,3,4,5)], brewer.pal(5, "Pastel1")[c(2,5,1,3)])
#grid::grid.raster(my_palette, int=F)

scale_colour_discrete = function(...) scale_colour_manual(..., values = palette())

dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
(p <- qplot(carat, price, data = dsamp, colour = clarity)) # default palette

palette(my_palette)
p # custom colors
```

Comment: This looks great Batiste, but I have a hard time integrating the idea into my code. Should I use "scale_colour_discrete = function(...) scale_colour_manual(..., values = palette())" instead of "scale_colour_manual(breaks=c("r","á/b","ő/é","w/s (0.3)","w/s (0.2)"), values=c("green","orange","blue","pink","yellow"))"?

Comment: feel free to experiment and use what works best for you. The idea is to define your own vector of preferred colours, and feed them as values to scale_colour_manual. I use the palette() trick so that my code runs regardless of whether I forgot to include my custom colours in my script.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without creating an additional function is to use the HEX code. If you use the RcolorBrewer website, each palette colour has one.
*Example:*

scale_color_manual(values=c("#1f78b4","#a6cee3","#fc8d62","#e41a1c"))

With the codes in the order that you need them in accordance with your other ggplot2 layers. This way, you can cherry-pick and combine colors from different RcolorBrewer palettes.